# Is there an ARM Template to create an ASE (App Service Environmet) and multiple ASPs' (App Service Plans) under it

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

```json
"resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
                "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
                "kind": "ASEV2",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "InternalLoadBalancingMode": "[if(equals(parameters('ASEType'), 'External'), '0', '3')]",
                    "virtualNetwork": {
                        "Id": "[resourceId(parameters('VNetResourceGroupName') ,'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/',parameters('vnetName'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
                    }
                },
                "tags": {}          
            },
            {
                "condition": "[equals(parameters('appServicePlanStatus'),'enable')]",
                "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
                "name": "appServicePlan-nestedTemplate01",
                "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                "resourceGroup": "[parameters('appserviceplanRGName')]",
                "properties": {
                    "mode": "Incremental",
                    "template": {
                        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                        "resources": [
                            {
                                "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
                                "sku": {
                                    "Tier": "[variables('skutier')]",
                                    "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
                                },
                                "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
                                "name": "[parameters('appserviceplanname')]",
                                "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
                                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": "[parameters('appserviceplanname')]",
                                    "workerSize": "",
                                    "workerSizeId": "",
                                    "numberOfWorkers": "",
                                    "reserved": "[if(equals(parameters('kind'),'windows'),bool('false'),bool('true'))]",
                                    "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('aseName')]"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/',parameters('aseName'))]"
                ]
            }
    
        ]
    }
```

The above template creates ASE and an ASP I would like to create multiple ASPS' under an ASE in one template.

Comment: Adding another serverFarm resource in your nested template doesn't work?

Comment: @ardoRic I would like to pass inputs dynamically with another json input file and create multiple ASPs' by using copy can we do this ?